# WPF datagrid empty row at bottom

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I bind my datagrid using

```
//fill datagrid
public DataTable GameData
{
    get
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(IMDB.WebPage.Class.Config.XMLPath,
        FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fs, Encoding.Default);
        ds.ReadXml(reader);
        fs.Close();
        DataTable temp = ds.Tables[0];
        return ds.Tables[0];
     }
 }
```

For some reason I get an empty row at the bottom. And sometimes after clicking on some buttons and checkboxes in the grid, more empty rows are added.

Why is this? And how do I block this?

Answer (score 504, accepted):

Sounds like you probably have `CanUserAddRows` set to true for the DataGrid. Just add

```
CanUserAddRows="false"
```

to the XAML.

Comment: keep in mind that even if the check box in the grid's properties is unchecked you have to explicitly add that line of code to hide the additional row (or check and uncheck the check box)

Comment: If you don't want code behind, add attribute CanUserAddRows="False". It looks like a bug in WPF that you have to set it to false explicitly.

Comment: I rather have the opposite problem. It does not create an empty row, while I'd rather want that.

Answer (score 27):

It also works with the attribute:

```
IsReadOnly="true"
```

Comment: This worked better than CanUserAddRows & CanUserDeleteRows

Answer (score 14):

If your backing collection that implements `IEditableCollectionView` returns true from its `CanAddNew` method, the DataGrid will assume that is what you want to do.

There's a good overview here:[Overview of the editing features in the WPF DataGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/vinsibal/overview-of-the-editing-features-in-the-wpf-datagrid)

Answer (score 3):

If you're creating DataGrid on-the-fly through Source Code...

```
DataGrid grid = new DataGrid();

grid.CanUserAddRows = false;

//... 
grid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
grid.Margin = new Thickness(10,20,10,10);
grid.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
grid.ItemsSource = //... and so on
```

Comment: If you do this while using WPF, you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Though the OP was asking how to REMOVE the empty row, the title isn't specific, and this article appeared in my search while trying to figure out how to ADD the empty row.  I found that, for the empty row to appear, it not only needs to have `CanUserAddRows="True"` but the `ItemsSource` needs to have a default constructor `public MyClass () { }`.