# In MahApps Metro DataGridCheckBoxColumn how can I programmatically return checkbox values? (and fix extra row)

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, datagrid, mahapps.metro

I know this isn't necessarily specific to MahApps Metro DataGridCheckBoxColumns, but I figured that information may help someone answer my question.

I'm trying to do two things with my DataGridCheckBox Column in [MahApps Metro](http://mahapps.com/)

**1. I would like to have two separate datagrids, and have the ability to return the value in the second column of whichever row is selected**

For example, if I had a datagrid that looked like this:

[image]

When someone has the checkbox associated with 2 selected, and the checkbox associated with Red selected, I would like a messagebox to show "2 Red".

**my .xaml**

```
        <DataGrid Name="numberGrid"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=numberGrid}"
              Grid.Row="0"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  Width="300"
                  Height="auto">
            <DataGrid.Columns>

                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn ElementStyle="{DynamicResource MetroDataGridCheckBox}"
                                    EditingElementStyle="{DynamicResource MetroDataGridCheckBox}"
                                    Header="Select"
                                    Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}, Path=IsSelected, Mode=OneWay}"
                                    />
                <DataGridTextColumn     Header="Numbers" 
                                    Binding="{Binding Number, Mode=OneWay}"
                                        Width="*"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>




        <DataGrid Name="colorGrid"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=colorGrid}"
              Grid.Row="0"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              Width="300">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn ElementStyle="{DynamicResource MetroDataGridCheckBox}"
                                    EditingElementStyle="{DynamicResource MetroDataGridCheckBox}"
                                    Header="Select"
                                    Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}, Path=IsSelected, Mode=OneWay}"
                                    />
                <DataGridTextColumn     Header="Colors" 
                                    Binding="{Binding Color, Mode=OneWay}"
                                        Width="*"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

**my .cs** with the pseudocode of what I think should happen commented out.

```
    ObservableCollection<MahAppsNumbers> MAnumbers = new ObservableCollection<MahAppsNumbers>
    {

        new MahAppsNumbers{Number = "1"},
        new MahAppsNumbers{Number = "2"},
        new MahAppsNumbers{Number = "3"},
        new MahAppsNumbers{Number = "4"}


    };

    public class MahAppsNumbers
    {
        public string Number { set; get; }
    }

    ObservableCollection<MahAppsAccents> MAcolors = new ObservableCollection<MahAppsColors>
    {
        new MahAppsColors{Color = "Red"},
        new MahAppsColors{Color = "Orange"},
        new MahAppsColors{Color = "Yellow"},
        new MahAppsColors{Color = "Green"}
    };

    public class MahAppsColors
    {
        public string Color { set; get; }
    }




    public myWindow()
    {




        InitializeComponent();

        numberGrid.ItemsSource = MAnumbers;
        colorGrid.ItemsSource = MAcolors;

        //Something like this maybe?  I know this isn't a thing you can do
        //string currentNumber = numberGrid.SelectedRow[1]; //to get the second column value
        //string currentColor = colorGrid.SelectedRow[1];
        //MessageBox.Show(currentNumber + currentColor);


    }
```

**2. For bonus points, why do I have an extra row at the end?**

I've found TONS of solutions for this, that are all basically the [same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783839/wpf-datagrid-empty-row-at-bottom).  But that doesn't solve my problem.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit 1**

Since I want this even to happen every time a box is selected, I'm trying something like this inside of myWindow()

```
this.numberGrid.SelectedCellsChanged += new SelectedCellsChangedEventHandler(numberGrid_SelectionChanged);
```

and adding a function that hopefully someone can point me in the right direction to fixing.

```
private void numberGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectedCellsChangedEventArgs e)
{
     MessageBox.Show(numberGrid.SelectedItem.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Binding like this,

```
<DataGridCheckBoxColumn  Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Now you have a Property `IsSelected` add this to your collection which binds your `DataGrid`. When you check your `CheckBox IsSelected property Set` will call and set it to True, now in your collection has the `IsSelected` True for which its checked.